# Trouble getting a rule to match without any discerning identifiers

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am looking to find a way to match a URL like `www.domain.tld/about` or `www.domain.tld/contact` within my `.htaccess` file. The rule has to be dynamic as the pages come from a CMS so the rule needs to be able to accept any newly created page.

Currently I have the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ([^/]+)$    ?cat=generic&page=$1 [L]
```

The issue is that without a trailing `/` or anything else to help identify the catch, it just triggers a `404` error page. I used to have the rewrite as:

```
RewriteRule ([^/]+)/$   ?cat=generic&page=$1 [L]
```

but decided to not have trailing slashes on the end of URL's, unless its a folder path.

Thank you anyone who can help on the issue.

Comment: What file handles the routing? index.php? I suppose you need to specify index.php as the filename then `RewriteRule ([^/]+)$    index.php?cat=generic&page=$1 [L]`

Comment: with or without index.php before the ? it still works the same so that will not make a difference. Any other ideas? It is the regular expression that needs tweaking to get this working imo.

Comment: When you enter `http://www.domain.tld?cat=generic&page=about` in your browser, does it load the page properly?

Comment: Hi, sorry, entering `http://www.domain.tld?cat=generic&page=about-us` does bring back the correct page, I forgot I use `about-us` and not `about`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this rule **on top of all other rules** i your .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^broadleaf$ /products/desktops/broadleaf-one [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /?cat=generic&page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

`/?$` makes trailing slash optional.

Comment: Can you look into Apache's error.log and tell me what error do you see there. Also please post your complete .htaccess in your question.

Comment: Error log is as follows --- www.domain.tld [Thu Aug 22 11:48:59 2013] [error] [client 78.109.178.130:56651] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Comment: works like a charm. Had to shuffle a few things round in my .htaccess file. I have not edited in the contents of the file as its not worth it now. Thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: Hi, not sure if your interested in helping further, I have found that if I place `RewriteRule ^broadleaf$ /products/desktops/broadleaf-one [R=301,L]` before `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /?cat=generic&page=$1 [L,QSA]` it makes the latter error 500, if the reverse is done then the former redirect does not work. Is there a way in which to get both working? ty

Comment: That rule must be placed before my suggested rule above. As long as you have `RewriteCond` as suggested above it should not throw 500 error. If it does then please let me know what error you see in Apache error log. (I have edited answer above for you)

Comment: thank you very very much, you are a knight in shining armour! that solved the issue again :D

Comment: You're most welcome, glad that it worked out for you again :)